# Convergency of Adomian decomposition for solving on nonlinear algebraic systems of equations

Tags: sequences-and-series, nonlinear-system

As far as I've managed to understand [this method](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82416777.pdf), idea is the following. If we have equation like $x=1-a x^2$, then we assume that $a x^2$ is small and get zero approximation for the root $x_0 = 1$. We can calculate next orders based on Adomain polynomials and get the result:

$$x \to 1 - a + 2 a^2 - 5 a^3 + 14 a^4 - 42 a^5 + ...$$
(In fact what happens behind scenes here is that same as standard approaches pertrubation theory in physics.) For square equations I see that these series converge to correct root if square equation has a root. My question is if this works multivariate equations, i.e. we have multivariate nonlinear equation with at least one root, do we have a guarantee that Adomian series will converge?